# Can't split tensor due to () shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

If i print `tensor.shape` I get this:

```py
tf.Tensor(b["Can we make this quick?  Roxanne Korrine and Andrew Barrett are having an incredibly horrendous public break- up on the quad.  Again.",
"Well, I thought we'd start with pronunciation, if that's okay with you.",
'Not the hacking and gagging and spitting part.  Please.',
"Okay... then how 'bout we try out some French cuisine.  Saturday?  Night?"], 
shape=(), dtype=string)
```

Why my shape is () ? I want to split each phrase to 2 tensors:

- Tensor A will have phrases 1 and 3
- Tensor B will have phrases 2 and 4

But I cannot use split because my tensor shape is (). I've tried to change its shape with `set_shape(1, )` but I get this:

```py
ValueError: Tensor's shape () is not compatible with supplied shape [1, None]
```

Comment: what is `b` here?

Comment: @NicolasGervais b stands for binary in tensorflow (if i'm not wrong). i've just formatted its output so that it could be more readable

Comment: Please add code to show how you created the tensor of strings

Comment: You can use `tf.strings.split('hello world').numpy()`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is common tensor are design to handle multi dimension (array within an array) but it looks like you got a single array wrap around a single string.

Just do normal string processing

```py
split_str = my_str.split('\n')
```